# How to design the cassandra table for one query with a ordering and limit?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

Now I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_by_user(
  user_id    bigint,
  post_id    uuid,
  post_at    timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,post_id)
);
```

I want to select last **10** rows with operator `IN` for `user_id` and ordering by **post_at** field.

Also I read a good article:
http://planetcassandra.org/blog/the-in-operator-in-cassandra-cql/

I can nit use query: `WHERE post_at = time AND user_id IN (1,2)` because I need all notes, not for a concrete date.

How i can change my design schema? Thank you.

I change on:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_by_user (
  user_id    bigint,
  post_id    uuid,
  post_at    timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (post_at DESC);
```

Think it is a good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using this approach: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use-slice-partition.html

Comment: It helped me, вот is left one trouble, can I ask here or must create a new question?

Comment: If the answer only partially solves the problem, you could explain what it's missing. If the remaining issue is separate, a new question would be better. One of the ideas of SO is that questions and answers remain around for others that have the problem in the future. So, the value of a separate question is that someone else is more likely to find the help they need.